# Is there any file-based shell-friendly key-value store?

Tags: database, shell, key-value-store

I'm looking for a key-value store, which runs like this:

```
$ tool --db file.db put foo bar
$ tool --db file.db get foo
bar
```

I want the following properties:

- Standalone and file-based: I don't want server-client. One file one database. Deleting the file, deleting the database.
- Shell friendly: I mainly use it in shell, so each command invocation has only one query. The bootstrap needs to be fast. Most existing DBMS are quite slow in this sense. By bootstrap, I mean creating worker process/thread, preloading metadata, maintaining a in-memory copy of the most recent query result. All these are not needed if we have only one query to run.
- Preferably it's implemented in C/C++, because managed language such as Java and Python bootstrap slowly by itself.

[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) is a standalone tool, but I don't need a relational DB.

[LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) looks like a good file-based DB, but its bootstrap time is long. It keeps newly added entries in a in-memory log, and flushes it to the main DB file in batch. If a command only adds one entry, the performance will be very poor.

[kv-bash](https://github.com/damphat/kv-bash) is very shell friendly and bootstraps fast, but it creates lots of small files (one file per entry).

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with this, but have you considered redis?

Comment: How about Berkeley DB?

Comment: @user8470034 Redis is in-memory. Although it supports persistence, it has to load the whole database to memory, which is very slow.

Comment: @JamesBrown Berkeley DB doesn't come with a command-line query tool. From its C API, "Calling DB->open() is a relatively expensive operation, and maintaining a set of open databases will normally be preferable to repeatedly opening and closing the database for each new query." I think it's not designed for single query, but it might not be slow in implementation. I guess further checking needed.

Comment: Yes, so it seems. I couldn't even find a third party client with mild googling.

Comment: I ran in to this while googling: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/src/dbmtools.man.html

Comment: @JamesBrown Looks very good. I will definitely further investigate it.

Comment: FWIW, I created a database available over HTTP that you can script with curl; checkout https://github.com/amirouche/deuspy/